# SQL Server - Pass Server and database to stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

(Excuse the amateur nature of the question)

I am trying to pass the servername and database name to a stored procedure which does some logging as follows

```
exec [dbo].[Logger]
      @Server = @@servername,
      @Database = db_name(db_id()),
      @Task = 'Some task';
```

but I keep getting this error -

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
>   Incorrect syntax near 'db_id'.

I have got this to work using `declare @dbname varchar(255) = db_name(db_id());` at the top and then using that. But it seems like an unnecessary variable.

Thanks

Comment: db_name returns a NVarchar(128) not varchar(255)

Comment: That extra variable **is** indeed necessary since you **cannot** use functions in a stored procedure execution call - you need to have all values needed in variables and/or literals

Comment: duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967035/using-function-as-a-parameter-when-executing-a-stored-procedure

Comment: @mark make it an answe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
declare @servername varchar(100) = @@servername
declare @dbname = db_name(db_id())

exec [dbo].[Logger]
      @Server = @servername,
      @Database = @dbname,
      @Task = 'Some task'
```