# SQL: Adding getdate() as an extended property with EXEC sys.sp_updateextendedproperty

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, syntax, syntax-error, code-documentation

Situation: Trying to build out basic table notes utilizing extended properties on tables/views/sp and identifying a date where the extended property was modified to kick off events where a review is needed.

I have attempted a few approaches but cannot identify a syntax to assign a getdate value to the description below. I have also tried identifying a system table that would record a modified date, this would allow the user to not have to enter a modified date manually.

```
EXEC sys.sp_updateextendedproperty 
@name=N'ModifiedDate', @value= getdate(), 
@level0type=N'SCHEMA',
@level0name=N'dbo',
@level1type=N'TABLE',
@level1name=N'tablename'
```

> Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Any help or direction on syntax is much appreciated.  The documentation is still in infancy, if there is a better solution I am open to those opinions.

Comment: It is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967035/using-function-as-a-parameter-when-executing-a-stored-procedure

Comment: Thanks for the helpful response Venkatesh -- I missed this one in my search earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use variable or literal:

```
DECLARE @d SQL_VARIANT = getdate();

EXEC sys.sp_updateextendedproperty 
@name=N'ModifiedDate', @value= @d,
@level0type=N'SCHEMA',
@level0name=N'dbo',
@level1type=N'TABLE',
@level1name=N'tablename';
```

[EXECUTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> [ @parameter = ] { **value**
>                              | **@variable** [ OUTPUT ]
>                              | [ DEFAULT ]
>                              }